# How to use data URL in WordPress?

Tags: php, functions, images, themes, html

First of all, I don't know much about coding. I know HTML, CSS, and PHP, but only a little, just the basics. What I want to do is I want to load my favicon, site logo, and the featured images via HTML. I know that I have to base64 encode them and insert them via data URL and not HTTP URL. But there's no easy way to do that in WordPress. I searched on the internet, but I only get to do that on a static website, but not on WordPress.

So, now my question is how to do that in WordPress? How can I found the line or lines I need to edit? And what will happen when I will update WordPress or the theme?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to modify your theme, yes. I'd start with header.php in the theme, but where exactly the images are will depend on how the theme was built. You should make a new child theme with the modifications in rather than change the theme directly, so that they'll survive updates of the parent theme. If you do develop this by changing the theme directly then remember to copy the changes into a child theme afterwards.

Comment: Okay. But what will I exactly add or modify in header.php? I am using the Astra theme. I have also installed the Code Snippets plugin.

Comment: Hey, anyone reply, please! I am using the Astra theme. I have also installed the child theme. But I don't know how to find the function or the line of code I have to modify. Please, help me.